# Grease Pencil now showing up or rendering?

Tags: grease-pencil

I added grease pencil but it is neither showing up on viewport nor is it rendering in final image. I have Combined and Z pass enabled. I have used grease pencil before and successfully rendered it many number of times. Can anyone suggest me some strange setting that might be doing this.

Please dont ask me for the file as it is a pro-project which can't be shared.

Comment: may you share screenshot? Check if you are not at frame 0

Comment: @Crantisz I can tell what is happening. I just observed. There is an *image as plane* in front of camera which does not have Grease Pencil applied to it. So anything within the range of the **image** isn't showing GP whereas anything outside of it is rendering GP. (I am on 0th frame i chkd)

Comment: @Crantisz Now I can confirm that the Image infront of camera is blocking Grease Pencil from showing up. The image is a transparent png . How to fix it?

Comment: change alpha mode to alpha clip

Comment: @Crantisz I did, doesn't work.